# How to combine multiple statements in one output for tcpdf

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

I'm trying out tcpdf library and have two seperate statements, each of which give me certain information. when I remove one statement, am getting the PDF output without an error and now once I include the other statement. I get the below:

```
Call to a member function rowcount() on boolean in ...DIR... pointing to the second "  if($query->rowcount() > 0) {"
```

Is there a way in which I can write this? Ideally the output should be on one table seemlessly. Please also note that both statements are error free once executed individually.

N.B Am using the below as an example and not really that employee table and income table cannot be joined. The idea is to be helped on how I can use two different statements in one file.

```
        require_once("header.php");

        $tbl_header = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%" border="1">';
        $tbl_footer = '</table>';
        $tbl ='';

        //statement one
        $result = $odb -> query('select * from employee');
        if($result->rowcount() > 0) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                            $EmployeeID = $row['EmployeeID']; 
                            $EmployeeName = $row['EmployeeName']; 


         $tbl = '<tr>
          <td width="50%" align="right">Emp ID:<br/> '.$EmployeeID.' </td>
          <td  width="50%" align="right">Emp Name:<br/> '.$EmployeeName.' </td> 
          </tr>';
            }   
            }

        //statement two 
        $query = $odb -> query('select * from income');
              if($query->rowcount() > 0) {
                    foreach ($query as $rowb) {
                        $Code  = $rowb['Code'];
                        $IncomeName  = $rowb['IncomeName'];
                        $IncomeAmount  = $rowb['IncomeAmount'];


                      $tblb .= '<tr>
          <td width="20%" align="right">'.$Code.' </td>
          <td  width="40%" align="left">'.$IncomeName.' </td> 
          <td width="40%" align="right">'.$IncomeAmount.' </td>
          </tr>';
                    }
              }


        $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header. $tbl .$tblb . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');


        $pdf->Output(__DIR__ .'/paid_'.date('m-d-Y_hia').'.pdf', 'FI');
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of message

```
Call to a member function rowcount() on boolean
```

generally means that your query hasn't worked - instead of returning a results object that you can call rowcount or fetch or whatever on, it's returned `false`. So you need to see why the query has failed, and ideally deal with that in your code.

As your code isn't using the live queries, it's impossible to say why it might have failed. It is strange that you say they both work without error when executed separately - are you able to execute them one after another in any context, i.e. in a standard page where you just echo results? Or if you add a try..catch and enable PDO exception mode, does that give any clues why it might have failed?

Answer (score 0):

I figured what the problem was. It was using the same connection variable i.e $odb and this was causing a conflict. I created another connection and gave it a different variable name i.e $db. This meant that I had two different connection files. Notice that I have header.php  and headerb.php

```
        require_once("header.php");

        $tbl_header = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%" border="1">';
        $tbl_footer = '</table>';
        $tbl ='';

        //statement one
        $result = $odb -> query('select * from employee');
        if($result->rowcount() > 0) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                            $EmployeeID = $row['EmployeeID']; 
                            $EmployeeName = $row['EmployeeName']; 


         $tbl = '<tr>
          <td width="50%" align="right">Emp ID:<br/> '.$EmployeeID.' </td>
          <td  width="50%" align="right">Emp Name:<br/> '.$EmployeeName.' </td> 
          </tr>';
            }   
            }

        //statement two 
        require_once("headerb.php");
        $query = $db -> query('select * from income');
              if($query->rowcount() > 0) {
                    foreach ($query as $rowb) {
                        $Code  = $rowb['Code'];
                        $IncomeName  = $rowb['IncomeName'];
                        $IncomeAmount  = $rowb['IncomeAmount'];


                      $tblb .= '<tr>
          <td width="20%" align="right">'.$Code.' </td>
          <td  width="40%" align="left">'.$IncomeName.' </td> 
          <td width="40%" align="right">'.$IncomeAmount.' </td>
          </tr>';
                    }
              }


        $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header. $tbl .$tblb . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');


        $pdf->Output(__DIR__ .'/paid_'.date('m-d-Y_hia').'.pdf', 'FI');
```

Comment: Then there is something else wrong, to create a new connection for every query is never the correct solution, at best a workaround.

Comment: Yes, that does seem very strange. It'd be interesting to know more about the database library being used, perhaps it requires the first query to somehow be closed before a second one can be opened.